# What does ValueError mean?

Tags: python

I,m trying to calculate the shortest distance between a collection of points and a line segment. Everything goes well untill it has to calculate the distance using values from two sets of arrays one for the x distances and one for the y distances.

The line for calculating the distance is:

```
d = np.sqrt( dx**2 + dy**2 ).
```

It tells me that::

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3312,) (0,)
```

I've used the script before with another set of values and it works perfectly. But now it does not any more. And I tried tot find the meaning of the error message but have not been successful so far. Can someone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Numpy Operands could not be broadcast together with shape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856493/numpy-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be, that dx and dy are two arrays of different length, dx has a length of 3312, and dy a length of 0.
Better check if dy is correctly set.

If i reproduce your problem with two arrays of length 6 and 0  I get the same error, if I use two arrays of the same length it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

> ValueError
>    Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value

Demo:

```
>>> int("1")
1
>>> int("h")         # valueError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'
```