# Counting values along an axis in a 3D array that are greater than threshold values from a 2D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting

I have a 3D array of dimensions (200,200,3). These are images of dimensions (200,200) stacked using numpy.dstack. I would like to count the number of values along axis=2 that are greater than a corresponding 2D threshold array of dimensions (200,200). The output counts array should have dimensions (200,200). Here is my code so far.

```
import numpy as np

stacked_images=np.random.rand(200,200,3)
threshold=np.random.rand(200,200)
counts=(stacked_images<threshold).sum(axis=2)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (200,200,3) (200,200)
```

The code works if threshold is an integer/float value. For example.

```
threshold=0.3
counts=(stacked_images<threshold).sum(axis=2)
```

Is there a simple way to do this if threshold is a 2D array? I guess I am not understanding numpy broadcasting rules correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy \`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape ...\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856493/numpy-valueerror-operands-could-not-be-broadcast-together-with-shape)

Comment: Extend `thresh` to `3D` : `(stacked_images > threshold[...,None]).sum(2)`.

Comment: @kazemakase I had looked through the link you provided earlier. The general answer given there is correct to look into numpy broadcasting rules.  However, I was not aware how to extend my array into 3D.

Comment: @Divakar Your solution worked. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is expecting to make a value by value operation. In your case you seem to be wanting to know if any value in the full Z (axis=2) trace exceeds the equivalent x, y value in threshold.

As so just make sure threshold has the same shape, namely by building a 3D threshold using whatever method you prefer. Since you mentioned [numpy.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

stacked_images = np.random.rand(10, 10, 3)
t = np.random.rand(10, 10)
threshold = np.dstack([t, t, t])
counts = (stacked_images < threshold).sum(axis=2)
print(counts)
```

, which results in:

```
[[2 0 3 3 1 3 1 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 3]
 [2 1 3 0 3 2 1 3 1 3]
 [2 0 0 3 3 2 0 2 0 1]
 [1 3 0 0 0 3 0 2 1 2]
 [1 1 3 2 3 0 0 3 0 3]
 [3 1 0 1 2 0 3 0 0 0]
 [3 1 2 1 3 0 3 2 0 2]
 [3 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 2 2 0 3 0 0 2 3 1]]
```